# how to write where condition in mysql object

Tags: mysql, json, csv

In Table A I have a column like `options` with a value like below.

```
{
    "info_buyRequest": {
        "qty": "1.0000"       
    },
    "options": [       
        {
            "label": "Prescription",
            "value": "|power_base:-2.00|bc_base:8.9|dia_base:14.2|qty:1",
            "print_value": "|power_base:-2.00|bc_base:8.9|dia_base:14.2|qty:1",
            "option_id": "403",
            "option_type": "field",
            "option_value": "|power_base:-2.00|bc_base:8.9|dia_base:14.2|qty:1",
            "custom_view": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a  Table B with columns like `power_code` , `bc_code` , `dia_code`.
I have to compare Table b columns with Table A object `power_base`,`bc_base`,`dia_base` .

Or if it is possible with PHP?

Create a table statement.

```
CREATE TABLE `sales_order_item` (
  `item_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Item ID',
  `order_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Order ID',
  `parent_item_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Parent Item ID',
  `quote_item_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Quote Item ID',
  `store_id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store ID',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Created At',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Updated At',
  `product_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Product ID',
  `product_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Product Type',
  `product_options` text COMMENT 'Product Options',
  `weight` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Weight',
  `is_virtual` smallint(5) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Is Virtual',
  `sku` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Sku',
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name',
  `description` text COMMENT 'Description',
  `applied_rule_ids` text COMMENT 'Applied Rule Ids',
  `additional_data` text COMMENT 'Additional Data',
  `is_qty_decimal` smallint(5) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Is Qty Decimal',
  `no_discount` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'No Discount',
  `qty_backordered` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Qty Backordered',
  `qty_canceled` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Qty Canceled',
  `qty_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Qty Invoiced',
  `qty_ordered` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Qty Ordered',
  `qty_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Qty Refunded',
  `qty_shipped` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Qty Shipped',
  `base_cost` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Cost',
  `price` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Price',
  `base_price` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Price',
  `original_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Original Price',
  `base_original_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Original Price',
  `tax_percent` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Tax Percent',
  `tax_amount` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Tax Amount',
  `base_tax_amount` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Tax Amount',
  `tax_invoiced` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Tax Invoiced',
  `base_tax_invoiced` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Tax Invoiced',
  `discount_percent` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Discount Percent',
  `discount_amount` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Discount Amount',
  `base_discount_amount` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Discount Amount',
  `discount_invoiced` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Discount Invoiced',
  `base_discount_invoiced` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Discount Invoiced',
  `amount_refunded` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Amount Refunded',
  `base_amount_refunded` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Amount Refunded',
  `row_total` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Row Total',
  `base_row_total` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Row Total',
  `row_invoiced` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Row Invoiced',
  `base_row_invoiced` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Row Invoiced',
  `row_weight` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Row Weight',
  `base_tax_before_discount` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Tax Before Discount',
  `tax_before_discount` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tax Before Discount',
  `ext_order_item_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ext Order Item ID',
  `price_incl_tax` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Price Incl Tax',
  `base_price_incl_tax` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Price Incl Tax',
  `row_total_incl_tax` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Row Total Incl Tax',
  `base_row_total_incl_tax` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Row Total Incl Tax',
  `discount_tax_compensation_amount` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Discount Tax Compensation Amount',
  `base_discount_tax_compensation_amount` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Discount Tax Compensation Amount',
  `discount_tax_compensation_invoiced` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Discount Tax Compensation Invoiced',
  `base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Discount Tax Compensation Invoiced',
  `discount_tax_compensation_refunded` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Discount Tax Compensation Refunded',
  `base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Discount Tax Compensation Refunded',
  `tax_canceled` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tax Canceled',
  `discount_tax_compensation_canceled` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Discount Tax Compensation Canceled',
  `tax_refunded` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tax Refunded',
  `base_tax_refunded` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Tax Refunded',
  `discount_refunded` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Discount Refunded',
  `base_discount_refunded` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Discount Refunded',
  `gift_message_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Gift Message ID',
  `gift_message_available` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Gift Message Available',
  `free_shipping` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Free Shipping',
  `weee_tax_applied` text COMMENT 'Weee Tax Applied',
  `weee_tax_applied_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Weee Tax Applied Amount',
  `weee_tax_applied_row_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Weee Tax Applied Row Amount',
  `weee_tax_disposition` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Weee Tax Disposition',
  `weee_tax_row_disposition` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Weee Tax Row Disposition',
  `base_weee_tax_applied_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Weee Tax Applied Amount',
  `base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Weee Tax Applied Row Amnt',
  `base_weee_tax_disposition` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Weee Tax Disposition',
  `base_weee_tax_row_disposition` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Weee Tax Row Disposition',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Sales Order Item';
```

Comment: Oh no! Delimited lists inside a JSON Object property!! You do love to make life difficult

Comment: Don't use regex with JSON. This seems like a bad schema.

Comment: I think I would go fo doing anything with this data in PHP

Comment: Please post your `CREATE TABLE` statement. It's unclear how your posted JSON maps to your MySQL tables.

Comment: @RiggsFolly haha.. I didn't make life difficult my client made it for me.

Comment: This isn't a PHP problem - it's a database design problem - and you have a fundamentally broken database design. You should fix that _first_ before doing anything else.

Comment: Use a JSON library to parse both A and B. In A, split "value" by `|` and then compare?

Comment: @Dai No this is a Magento framework's default table.. it's just a text column.

Comment: I would be tempted to refactor the stupid properties so at least they are valid JSON bu tI doubt you can do that now as  it would likely break something somewhere else in the app

Comment: @JeffC That would require reading all of the rows and sending them to the client - that's not how database queries should work.

Comment: @ramesh Magento stores data in tables, not as nested JSON - so why did you post JSON? Again, **post your `CREATE TABLE` statement** otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: @Dai A guess I admit, but I expect Magento allows bad developers to developer bad plugins :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, that's probably what happened - but if you think this is bad you should see the WordPress ecosystem...

Comment: @Dai I have. I looked, I scremed out loud like a little girl, and I have vowed never to go back there ever again. There be _DRAGONS_ Bloomin big _DRAGONS_ :)

Comment: @Dai I have added the statement.

Comment: Any clue about which column holds this mess

Comment: @RiggsFolly Use MySQL Workbench to browse the tables.